# how do you add up a bunch of conditional statement answers on python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

How do I add the answers off all these conditional statements?

I know these are really simple conditional statements. I'm just curious about how you would add all the answers with python pandas

something like this if it would work A + B + C

```
A = if 5 < 7:
    print 4 + 6
else:
    print 12 - 6

B = if 10 < 7:
    print 6 + 6
else:
    print 12 - 3

 C = if 11 < 7:
    print 6 + 6
else:
    print 12 - 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was better before the edit, but you need to create a variable initialised as 0, then add the answer.

You could do:

```
sum_variable = 0
if a>b:
    sum_variable += c+d
else:
    sum_variable += c+f
```

Or, in the first form before your edit:

```
sum_variable = 0
sum_variable += c+d if a>b else c+f
```

You can look that up the specifics, but the concept is the same, that you create an intermediate variable that you can add the value to.

Another option, though less conventional, would be to add to an array and then sum the values of the array at the end.